# How do I fix an escape string

Tags: php

I'm just creating a comment form and I stumble upon this error

```
mysql_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in D:\xampp\htdocs\test\pages\blogprocessing.php on line 61
```

I don't really know why it's giving me it, I'm not expert at PHP but I could really use your guys help..

Part of my code...

```
    <?php 
 $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['comment']); 
 $blogID = $_POST['blogID']; //retrieve the blogID from the hidden form field
 $authorID = $_SESSION['username']; 

 $sql = "INSERT INTO comment (blogID, authorID, datePosted, comment) VALUES 
('$blogID', '$authorID', NOW(), '$comment')"; //sql query
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($connection)); //run the query
```

Thanks! :)

?>

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php check for correct argument passing.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. Try: `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'], $connection);`

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. The first parameter to mysql_real_escape_string is not a string.

As the doc say ( https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string ), the first parameter has to be the escaped string and the second the resource identifier.

The good way is :

```
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment'], $connection);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PHP Manual and your error:

`mysql_real_escape_string` exepts first Parameter to be string, not Connection handler.

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous speakers. Although read the documentation carefully:

```
Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
```

**It is highly recommended to drop mysql support! Use a library like mysqli, it also has escape string. Link below.**

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php